# How to install external engines in Lucas chess?

Tags: engines

I downloaded several chess engines ,and tried to add them with the help of engine configuration, but Lucas wanted .exe type file. My downloaded engine files were not shown because they were in the ZIP format. Is there any solution to it?

Comment: You probably need to unzip files first, for which you can use 7-zip program.

Comment: It's installed after I've unzipped.